# Postgres, duplicate unique index

Tags: postgresql, unique-index

I have a unique index column named "hash"

However when I run query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM urls_0
 WHERE hash = '\x0009cb31d8a6c0c64f6877c22a781804'::bytea
```

There are two rows and I can not reindex that index because of unique violation. What happen here. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.2

Comment: Are you **100% sure** that this *unique* index exists for the table *urls_0* solely on the column named *hash*?

Comment: Please, could you connect to the database, execute the following query and post the result here? `SELECT indexrelid::regclass, indisunique, indisvalid FROM pg_catalog.pg_index WHERE indrelid = 'urls_0'::regclass;`

Comment: @MarceloZabani: I'm sure

Comment: @MatheusOl: The result is true all. But I have fixed my system by manual removed the duplicated row.

Answer (score 2):

It could happen if you use CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY clause.

from [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY):

> If a problem arises while scanning the table, such as a uniqueness violation in a unique index, the CREATE INDEX command will fail but leave behind an "invalid" index. This index will be ignored for querying purposes because it might be incomplete; however it will still consume update overhead.

Comment: I think may be this is the right answer, but I do not use CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY. The index is created very first.