# PostgreSQL duplicate key when update non-unique column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run this query bellow on PostgreSQL 9.3.2. Can anyone tell me why this query bellow throw unique violation exception while I do not update the unique column.

The contents table also have two trigger but it just insert and update other table.

```
Execute command failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "contents_0_uk"
DETAIL:  Key (hash)=(\x145806e0794729ba98f16e4e8ec723cb) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE contents cont
    SET     content         = tmp.content,
            primitive       = tmp.primitive,
            lang            = ARRAY[lang_id(tmp.lang[1]), lang_id(tmp.lang[2]), lang_id(tmp.lang[3])],
            percent         = tmp.percent,
            score           = tmp.score
    FROM tmp_post_bulk tmp
    WHERE tmp.cid = cont.id
            AND tmp.chash_matched = TRUE
            AND (
                    cont.content            != tmp.content
                    OR cont.primitive       != tmp.primitive
                    OR cont.percent         != tmp.percent
                    OR cont.score           != tmp.score
                    OR cont.lang            != ARRAY[lang_id(tmp.lang[1]), lang_id(tmp.lang[2]), lang_id(tmp.lang[3])]
            )"
PL/pgSQL function content_bulk() line 53 at SQL statement
! Query is: SELECT content_bulk();
```

Comment: Maybe the `contents_0_uk` constraint is on the tables updated by the triggers?

Can you post the definition of the table?

Comment: contents_0_uk is on contents_0 which is a partition of contents table. Trigger do not update any partition in contents table and the updated table do not have any trigger.

Comment: Well, double check the triggers. Something is altering the `hash` column behind your back. Is that column part of the `contents` table?

Comment: contents_0 table inherit the contents table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just find out the problem is the same as
[Postgres, duplicate unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811753/postgres-duplicate-unique-index)

Because there are duplicateds row in this table (unique column duplicated), so when the query update the duplicated rows, PostgreSQL throw exception.

I will manual remove the duplicated rows.